# Fixing text in two menu blocks when the browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have two menu items in a row. Each menu item is the span with the icon and text. The height of the block is larger than the icon, since there is additional logic when you hover the mouse over the block. I have simplified the example and do not include this code.

[image: Equal position]

When the browser window is reduced to a certain size. The text in one of the blocks (depending on the length of the caption) is shifted one line below.
And in the second it remains at the same level. It looks ugly.

[image]

What changes should be made to synchronize the display of both blocks? Tried to apply style
.ellipsis

```
{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
```

to tag h5

But it doesn't do anything good.
**What is the best way to proceed here?**

```css
 .dx-item {
            outline: 0;
        }

        .dx-box-item-content {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .dx-widget {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Roboto, RobotoFallback, "Noto Kufi Arabic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.2857;
        }

        .dx-card {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 2px 2px 3px;
        }

        .iconStylePl10 {
            padding-right: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .iconStyle {
            display: inline;
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        .fa,
        .fas {
            font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .fa-fw {
            text-align: center;
            width: 1.25em;
        }

        .adk-card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 97%;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .adk-card:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
        }

        h5 {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .h5block {
            height: 45px;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        }

       dxi-item:not(.item-card):hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
        }

       .spanProperties {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: 120%;
            line-height: normal;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }

        .greenColor {
            color: #00b373;
        }

        .ellipsis {
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

    <div class="dx-item" style="display: flex; min-height: auto; flex: 0 1 100px;">
        <div class="dx-box-item-content  dx-widget"
            style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: stretch; width: auto; height: auto; flex-basis: 0px; flex-grow: 1;">
            <div class="dx-item" style="display: flex; min-width: auto; flex: 0 1 1000px;">
                <dxi-item
                    style="padding: 8px; width: auto; height: auto; display: flex; flex-basis: 0px; flex-grow: 1; flex-direction: column;"
                    class="dx-box-item-content">
                    <span class="dx-card adk-card">
                        <i class="fas fa-hard-hat fa-fw iconStyle iconStylePl10 greenColor" style="font-size:48px;">
                        </i>
                        <span class="spanProperties">
                            <h5>
                                Super super super long caption
                            </h5>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </dxi-item>
            </div>
            <div class="dx-item" style="display: flex; min-width: auto; flex: 0 1 1000px;">
                <dxi-item 
                    style="padding: 8px; width: auto; height: auto; display: flex; flex-basis: 0px; flex-grow: 1; flex-direction: column;"
                    class="dx-box-item-content">
                    <span class="dx-card adk-card">
                        <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw iconStyle iconStylePl10 greenColor"
                            style="font-size: 48px;"></i>
                        <span class="spanProperties">
                            <h5>
                                Simple caption
                            </h5>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </dxi-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two rules ( `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` ) for the `.adk-card` class.

```
     .adk-card {
        display: flex; /*add*/
        align-items: center; /*add*/
        width: 100%;
        height: 97%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
```